# How to configure icinga2 apilistener logger

Tags: ubuntu, icinga2

icinga2 on ubuntu 16.04 logs every single api call to /var/log/syslog.

I`m attempting to run icinga2 on xenial (ubuntu 16.04.1). I get a log of api related statements in my syslog. I have some automated integration running every 3 seconds, producing 10+ lines per run.

```
Dec 16 15:02:43 dev-srv-01 icinga2[763]: [2016-12-16 15:02:41 -0500] information/HttpServerConnection: Request: GET /v1/objects/hosts/xxx?attrs[]=address&attrs[]=vars (root)
Dec 16 15:02:43 dev-srv-01 icinga2[763]: [2016-12-16 15:02:42 -0500] information/ApiListener: New client connection (no client certificate)
```

Indeed icinga logs actions (apilistener.cpp:403)

```
Log(LogInformation, "ApiListener") << "New client connection " << conninfo << " (no client certificate)";
```

How to I configure this log so it is less verbose? I couldn't quite figure it out from the documentation.

This is my configuration so far:

```
Disabled features: gelf graphite icingastatus mainlog opentsdb perfdata statusdata syslog
Enabled features: api checker command compatlog debuglog ido-mysql livestatus notification
```

I also create this file:
/etc/icinga2/conf.d/api-users.conf

```
object ApiUser "root" {
     password = "x.x"
     permissions = [ "objects/*/Host" ]
}
```

systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Icinga host/service/network monitoring system
After=postgresql.service mariadb.service carbon-cache.service mysql.service yslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/icinga2/prepare-dirs /usr/lib/icinga2/icinga2
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/icinga2 daemon -e /var/log/icinga2/error.log
ExecReload=/usr/lib/icinga2/safe-reload /usr/lib/icinga2/icinga2
PIDFile=/run/icinga2/icinga2.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The only way to prevent the log statements is to disable feature api, which of course isn't desirable.

I attempted configuring syslog, filelogger, in a .conf file to no avail.
Disabling features debuglog, mainlog, also result in spam.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that is an "Information"-level log entry.  To remove it you'll need to change your logging to a higher level.  In

```
/etc/icinga2/features-enabled/mainlog.conf
```

I have

```
object FileLogger "main-log" {
  severity = "information"
  path = LocalStateDir + "/log/icinga2/icinga2.log"
}
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#objecttype-filelogger) the next step up from "information" would be "warning".

It looks like the same setting should be available for the [`SyslogLogger`](https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/object-types#objecttype-sysloglogger) which should be the logger you're using.

Comment: works flawlessly for mainlog. apilistener statements do not make it to icinga2.log anymore. However the "syslog.conf" feature, configured for severity warning, still lets "information" apilistener statements through.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it could be a systemd thing.

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/icinga2 daemon -e /var/log/icinga2/error.log --log-level warning
```

fixes the issue in a brute-force way.

This is not quite what I was looking for, but I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing isn't actually the output of the SyslogLogger feature of Icinga2, but the standard output of the icinga2 process, hence the duplicate timestamp. [The documentation](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/14-features/#logging) says:

> When running Icinga 2 on a terminal log messages with severity information or higher are written to the console.

This can be avoided by telling systemd to redirect stdout to /dev/null:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/icinga2.service.d/stdout.conf
[Service]                                      
StandardOutput=null
```